# HTML5 - Scrollable Div container with partial fixed divs in it

Tags: css, html, overflow, css-position

I'm trying to create an app container which behaves similar to Microsoft Excel. It should scroll both horizontally and vertically, with headers on the left and top which are fixed but scroll with the content. Something like:

```
+---ScrollableContainer---------+
|+-a-++----b--------------------|-------------------+
||   ||                         |                   |
||   |+-------------------------|-------------------|
||   |+----Content--------------|-------------------+
||   ||                         |                   |
||   ||                         |                   |
+-------------------------------+                   |
 |   ||                                             | 
 |   ||                                             |
 +---++---------------------------------------------+
```

The `ScrollableContainer` is the target container of all. It's scrollable horizontally and vertically.

The content of the ScrollableContainer is 3 `div`s: `a`, `b` and `Content`.
The problem I'd like to resolve is that the position of `div` `a` must be fixed on left but it have to scroll up and down when ScrollableContainer scrolls up and down. Also, the `div` `b` must be fixed on top but it have to scroll left and right when ScrollableContainer scrolls up and down.
The `Content` div, finally, is free to scroll in any direction.
Try to imagine an "Agenda". The `a` `div` is the "HOUR" pivot, the `b` `div` is the "DAY" pivot and the `Content` is the agenda, split by hours and days. Pivots had to follow scroll.

**EDIT:**

*Below is a semi-working example: - AndyM*

```css
.rows {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    position:relative;
}
.rows > header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.rows > article {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:40px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    overflow-x:scroll;    
}
.cols {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.cols header {
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:green;
}
.cols article {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

row {
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
cell {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="rows">
    <header>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Text</cell>
        </row>
    </header>
    <article>
        <section class="cols">
            <header>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
            </header>
            <article>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                    <cell>Text</cell>
                </row>
            </article>
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
```

Problem with it is that the vertical scroll bar is out of site, and the `.col` header doesn't scroll. Should be enough to give an idea of what the goal is.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: Sorry, i've no code yet... all my attempts failed miserably :)

Comment: you should show your best attempt. this might help someone to answer your question

Comment: You are trying to replicate MS Excel, right? Like a basic sheet view.

Comment: Paste your best try!

Comment: The fact that you don't have any code and attempts is bad. However, this is a rather interesting setup. I'm working on a JSFiddle for you. I know it can be done because Google Sheets does it.

Comment: :( sorry but... I deleted all for discouragement. If you want i try to replicate it... but I never approached the result and I would not want to confuse.

Comment: Andy, Good point of view! Yes, it's the same operation...

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear what you are going for, and to give code which is partly working. I'm not sure how to get it from where it is to what you want, but maybe someone else can figure it out.

Comment: Also, here's a plugin which can do it. http://www.massless.org/_tests/grid1/?s=1&r=40&c=40

Comment: Andy, thank you for the time spent... I've tried to use "divs" because i need that the content will not a tabular data. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this sort of scrolling behavior, you will either need to use an iframe or do write custom scrolling in javascript. With an iframe, you could just set divs 'a' and 'b' to be fixed in their position, but there could be a few complications. With javascript, you could write something like this:

```
var x=0, y=0;
ScrollableContainer.onwheel = function(e) {
  if(firefox) {
    x+=e.deltaX*16;
    y+=e.deltaY*16;
  } else {
    x+=e.deltaX;
    y+=e.deltaY;
  }
  a.style.marginTop = y + 'px';
  b.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
  content.style.marginTop = y + 'px';
  content.style.marginLeft = y + 'px';
};
```

This has not been tested, but for this to work, divs 'a', 'b', and 'content' must each be in their own container, but you can use these containers to position your divs however you want to.